# Find maximum in sliding window in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, java-8, deque

I was doing one question to find maximum number , given an input array and a sliding windows of given length.

Input

```
nums = [-4,2,-5,1,-1,6]
window_size = 3
```

Output

```
result = [2,2,1,6]
```

The solution uses deque data structure to track the index and store the maximum value. Below is the code for the solution.

```
class MaxSlidingWindow {
    public static ArrayDeque<Integer> findMaxSlidingWindow(int[] arr, int windowSize) {
        ArrayDeque<Integer> result = new ArrayDeque<>(); // ArrayDeque for storing values
        Deque<Integer> list = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(); // creating a linked list

        if (arr.length > 0) {
            // If window_size is greater than the array size,
            // set the window_size to nums.size()
            if (arr.length < windowSize)
                windowSize = arr.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < windowSize; ++i) {
                // Removing last smallest element index
                while (!list.isEmpty() && arr[i] >= arr[list.peekLast()]) {
                    list.removeLast();
                }

                // Adding newly picked element index
                list.addLast(i);
            }

            for (int i = windowSize; i < arr.length; ++i) {
                result.add(arr[list.peek()]);

                // Removing all the elements indexes which are not in the current window
                while ((!list.isEmpty()) && list.peek() <= i - windowSize)
                    list.removeFirst();

                // Removing the smaller elements indexes which are not required
                while ((!list.isEmpty()) && arr[i] >= arr[list.peekLast()])
                    list.removeLast();

                // Adding newly picked element index
                list.addLast(i);
            }

            // Adding the max number of the current window in the result
            result.add(arr[list.peek()]);
            return result; // returning result
        } else
            return result;
    }
```

Now I couldn't get the condition mentioned in the while loop that says "removing all the elements indexes which are not in the current window"  `while ((!list.isEmpty()) && list.peek() <= i - windowSize)`  . How could have author  approached this condition `list.peek() <= i - windowSize`  to remove all the elements which are not in current window.

If some one can give me a break down that how we can reach to this logic or is there any other intuitive condition that does the same job . It would be better if I can get some easy explanation of the above condition used by the author.

Secondly the author has used `++i` in the for loops . Is there a specific reason to choose the pre-increment for this question.

Comment: Pre-increments, if translated by the compiler without any optimization, are a lot faster, because it's simply a) increment and then b) return. Post-increment works like: a) create copy of value, b) increment original value c) return copy. Usually, especially in for-loops, there is not functional difference, so the compiler recognizes this unnecessary behavior and optimizes it away, so with default compiler (settings) you'll get just the same speed in both cases.

Comment: `new ArrayDeque<>(windowSize);` /(diamond operator and initial capacity, default is 16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is to build an increasing mono queue based on the sliding window.

Since the sliding window moves forward, you need to remove "possible" indices that are out of bound of the sliding window. That's what this line does:

```java
// Removing all the elements indexes which are not in the current window
while ((!list.isEmpty()) && list.peek() <= i - windowSize)
    list.removeFirst();
```

`i` is the index where the front of your sliding window lies and `i - windowsize` is the back of the window. You check wheather the head of the deque contains an index that is smaller and remove it, since it lies outside of the sliding window.

As for your second question, @JC677 explained it quite thoroughly in their comments. It doesn't make a functional difference here. It's probably the author's style.

Comment: ..thanks for the explanation. For instance in the given example in my question , when i = 4 , the sliding window would be = {-5,1,-1} and here the back of sliding window index would be 4 and (i - windowsize) would be 1. But the front of the window would be index 2 . Since the sliding window index wise is {2,3,4}. So in  my understanding what author is doing is he checking one step further back and compares with the head of the deque and if it is less or equal , it removes it . Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: That is correct. They are just making sure that no indices less than the start of the current sliding window are in the deque. Since the deque is a mono queue, it doesn't hold all the indices that are in the sliding window, because some of the are value-wise too small and are popped out from the front. Therefore, they need to check everytime wheather there is such an index or not, and can't just shift the smallest index out.